# regex : get part of text from url data

Tags: python, regex

I have many of this type of url :

```
http://www.example.com/some-text-to-get/jkl/another-text-to-get
```

I want to be able to get this :

```
["some-text-to-get", "another-text-to-get"]
```

I tried this :

```
re.findall(".*([[a-z]*-[a-z]*]*).*", "http://www.example.com/some-text-to-get/jkl/another-text-to-get")
```

but it's not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind and lookahead:

```
import re
s = 'http://www.example.com/some-text-to-get/jkl/another-text-to-get'
final_result = re.findall('(?<=\.\w{3}/)[a-z\-]+|[a-z\-]+(?=$)', s)
```

Output:

```
['some-text-to-get', 'another-text-to-get']
```

Comment: I want only lowercase words, is that possible to do ? Can't make it work with `[a-z]`

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the 2 parts in a capturing group:

[`^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+).*/(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/tOq8QK/1)

That would match:

- `^` Match from the start of the string
- `https?://` Match http with an optional s followed by `://`
- `[^/]+/` Match not a forward slash using a negated character class followed by a forward slash
- `([^/]+)` Capture in a group (group 1) not a forward slash
- `.*` Match any character zero or more times
- `/` Match literally (this is the last slash because the `.*` is greedy
- `(.*)$` Match in a capturing group (group 2) zero or more times any character and assert the end of the line `$`

Your matches are in the first and second capturing group.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BPZOGV25534)

Or you could parse the url, get the path, split by a `/` and get your parts by index:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

o = urlparse('http://www.example.com/some-text-to-get/jkl/another-text-to-get')
parts = filter(None, o.path.split('/'))
print(parts[0])
print(parts[2])
```

Or if you want to get the parts that contain a `-` you could use:

```
parts = filter(lambda x: '-' in x, o.path.split('/'))
print(parts)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XWO60413)

Comment: Python 3: from urllib.parse import urlparse

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> s
"http://www.example.com/some-text-to-get/jkl/another-text-to-get"
```

You can use this regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r"/([a-z-]+)(?:/|$)", s)
['some-text-to-get', 'another-text-to-get']
```

Of course you can do this with Python string methods and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [e for e in s.split('/') if '-' in e]
['some-text-to-get', 'another-text-to-get']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture it using this regular expression:

`((?:[a-z]+-)+[a-z]+)`

- `[a-z]+` match one or more character
- `(?:[a-z]+-)` don't capture in group